# I have zero coding knowledge. How do I generate a set of images with randomized pixels?

Tags: templates, random, generator, pixel, preset

I would like to generate a set of images, based on a preset shape template, but with different color fills in each of the shapes, randomly, and all images unique (1 or more shapes can have the same colors but not all of them the same in 2 images).

I want to generate about 10,000 of them, will it be a very heavy task?

Here's an example to give a clearer picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Write a program to assign random colours to one template.

Step 2: Test your program to check that it works.  If you can't fix it then post you code here and ask.

Step 3: Extend your program to handle more than one template.  Test.  Be sure you meet the uniqueness criterion.  Again ask here if you cannot fix it yourself.

Better to start small and build on that.  Don't try to write the whole program in one go.  Small pieces of code are easier to get working.